# Query Elastic Search in Java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a connection to ElasticSearch to query some data in JAVA 7.

I have an http request that calls the ElasticSearch service and a query with data to be sent in the request.

I am looking for examples or someone who can guide me since I can not find too much information.

It is supposed to return a json, we are left with the value of the state "OK" or "error"

**HTTP Petition:**

http://HOSTELASTIC:9200/connectorreply/_search/?pretty

**Example Data Query**

`{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"targetIdentity\":"parevalo"}},{"\match\":{"\managedSystemId\":"managedsysiddeAD_SANITASDOM"}},{"\match\":{\"operation\":"RESET_PASSWORD"}},{\"range\" : {\"timestamp\" : {\"gt\" : 1598220469666}}}],"\must_not\":[],"\should":[]}},"\from\":0,"\size\":10,"\sort\":[],"\aggs\":{}`

Comment: Can you be more specific. You can check  [High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html)

Comment: Does the same query work fine through the console? If yes, try removing that pretty from the query param once.